# Uniform convergence of difference quotient

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fa.functional-analysis

Let $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ be a smooth function with *compact support*.

For $h>0$ define the difference quotient $\phi_h\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ by $\phi_h(t)=\dfrac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}$.

By definition, for fixed $t\in\mathbb R$, we have $\phi_h(t)\to\phi'(t)$ as $h\to 0$.

> Question: Can we conclude, that $\phi_h\to\phi'$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$ (as $h\to 0)$?

Motivation: This is used in a proof of Stone's Theorem on the existence of generators of operator groups I'm trying to understand.

Comment: I think the answer is yes: apply fundamental thm of calculus to write $\phi_h$ as an integral involving $\phi'$ and then use the fact that $\phi'$ is uniformly continuous (being continuous with compact support). Does that work?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Yes, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Taylor's theorem
$$\phi(t+h)=\phi(t)+h\phi'(t)+h^2\phi''(t+u(h,t)h)/2$$
where $0\le u(h,t)\le1$. So
$$\phi_h(t)=\phi'(t)+h\phi''(t+u(h,t)h)/2.$$
As $\phi''$ is in $C^\infty_c$ it's pretty clear that $\phi_h\to\phi'$
uniformly.

Comment: This works as well. Thank you!

This is an impressive demonstration of the power of those big theorems that one is taught in a first course on analysis.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, any function with uniformly continuous first derivative satisfies 
$$\|\phi_h-\phi'\|_\infty\leq \omega(|h|),$$
where $\omega$ is any modulus of continuity of $\phi'$ (just recall that $\phi_h(x)$ equals a value of $\phi'$ in a point within a distance $|h|$ from $x$).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity